# Using MatlabFunction to generate function for ODE45

Tags: matlab

So far, I have 2 symbolic differential equations that I would like to convert into a function that I can use as an input parameter into the MATLAB ode45 function. So far I have the following code:

```
eom = [[dphi; dlen]; [eom1; eom2]];
state_var2 = [phi len];
state_var_dot2 = [dphi dlen];
eom_f = matlabFunction(eom, 'file', 'iSpringPend_eom', 'vars', {t, [state_var2; state_var_dot2], m, g, k, l0});
```

and it generates a function that I can use, but when I plug that function, it takes indefinitely long to run. Is there any way to use matlabFunction so it returns a function that I can put into ode45 without taking so long to run?

Comment: What do you mean by 'plug'? The `ode45` takes long or `MatlabFunction`? Can you also add the part you use `ode45`?

Comment: I mean use the function handle generated by matlabFunction as the function entered into ode45. Here's my code: 
    [t2, sol2] = ode45(eom_f, tspan2, ic2, [], m2, g2, k2, l02);

Comment: It looks like you're doing things correctly. `matlabFunction` may not do a good job of optimizing your ODEs, but without knowing what your equations are there's no way we can tell if this is the case. Also, it looks like you have springs in your system. If your system is stiff, `ode45` will have a hard time solving it. Trying reducing the stiffness of the system, or using a solver like `ode15s`. Also, use the `'Stats'` option via `odeset` to check how many failed steps `ode45` is taking - this will give you an indication of how stiff the equations are.